# Permissions to distrbute a C++ Addin for Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have an Excel-Spreadsheet (xlsx file) in Excel 2013/2016 and an additional Excel addin (xll file).
This two files I plan to deliver to potential customers as a testversion for free.
Do I need a special permission/License from Microsoft for this purpose.
The used development tools, i.e. Excel 2013/2016 and Excel 2013 SDK will not be a part of my software just the xlsx and xll file.
Add: Is there an appropriate terms of use document available in the internet? Especially I would like to avoid to be liable. 
On the other hand I don't want my program/xll to be de-compiled/reverse engineered or commercially sold by any user.

Comment: Legal opinions are worth what you pay for them, and can leave the person giving them open to liability. tl;dr: get legal advice.

Comment: You don't need permission/license from Microsoft to distribute an Excel workbook or XLL addin. It would be sensible to include an EULA.